# ¿Alguien sabe como solucionar problema de Android Studio 4.0.1 en realidad aumentada?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

Ya intente instalando todas las dependencias e instale y des instale el plugin de Google SceneForm Tools(Beta) y no he logrado obtener el archivo **.sfb** por medio del **Import SceneForm asset**
Me genera el siguiente error y no he podido solucionarlo, las imagenes adjuntas hacen parte de  Un unico error por lo que la unión de ellas es solo Un error, es demasiado grande.
[image: error1]

[image: error2]

[image: error3]

[image: error4]

[image: error5]

Comment: ¿cuál error?, creo que te faltó agregarlo

Comment: @BetaM es correcto se me había olvidado, ya lo adjunte

Comment: @BetaM me podrías ayudar a saber el por qué?